# Where does IModel Apache Wicket retrieve an object?

Tags: wicket

First of all, please take a look at how IModel is used in this example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static List<IColumn> getTableColumns(
        final ReportParams reportParams, final boolean columnsSortable
    ) {
    List<IColumn> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn>();
    final Map<String,ToolInfo> eventIdToolMap = Locator.getFacade().getEventRegistryService().getEventIdToolMap();

    // site
    if(Locator.getFacade().getReportManager().isReportColumnAvailable(reportParams, StatsManager.T_SITE)) {
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new ResourceModel("th_site"), columnsSortable ? ReportsDataProvider.COL_SITE : null, ReportsDataProvider.COL_SITE) {
            @Override
            public void populateItem(Item item, String componentId, IModel model) {
                final String site = ((Stat) model.getObject()).getSiteId();
                String lbl = "", href = "";
                Site s = null;
                try{
                    s = Locator.getFacade().getSiteService().getSite(site);
                    lbl = s.getTitle();
                    href = s.getUrl();
                }catch(IdUnusedException e){
                    lbl = (String) new ResourceModel("site_unknown").getObject();
                    href = null;
                }
                item.add(new ImageWithLink(componentId, null, href, lbl, "_parent"));
            }
        });
    }
```

And my questions are:

- How does populateItem get an input for IModel parameter?
- I cannot find any code in this application, which explicitly constructs IModel object. Is it correct for me to assume that the object is retrieved directly from a table in the database? I'm thinking of this because Mapping Hibernate is used for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models are created using the IDataProvider you provide to the [DataTable](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/DataTable.html) (DataTable constructor will also take your IColumn List) .
The IDataProvider could use Hibernate - hard to say without having more information on that implementation.

Comment: Yes I've just found a class which implements IDataProvider but is there an easy way to identify whether IDataProvider relies on the database?

Comment: Check the _Iterator<? extends T> iterator(int first, int count)_ implementation of the IDataProvider.